# Mysql Cloud SQL support for vertical partition

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, partitioning

I want to partition my table by date. We are using CloudSQL instance for hosting our Mysql db. Does Cloud SQL support vertical partitioning?  If yes, would it be similar to Mysql?

Comment: MySQL does not support Vertical Partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud SQL for MySQL is basically a fully managed MySQL Community Edition databases by GCP. As mentioned in the comment, if the feature is not supported by MySQL itself, unfortunately you cannot expect that it will appear as a feature in Cloud SQL as well.

Here's the doc per each supported version which will inform you that vertical partitioning is not supported in MySQL 8.0, 5.7, and 5.6 (you can switch the doc version on their page):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-overview.html